# TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not GeojsonFile

Tags: python, gridfs

datafile = open(filename, "r");
TypeError: expected str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not GeojsonFile

can someone help me why this happen? i want to read spatial data in geojson format.

Act i want to store geojson data into the database. I already connect the database which is MongoDB database. Im using gridfs to overcome the limitation, but first i need to read the data and store into the database.

many thanks

```
    #read in the spatial data
filename = "/dami_data/data1/countries.geojson"
geojfile = pygeoj.load(filename)
for feature in geojfile:
    print(feature.geometry.type)
    print(feature.geometry.coordinates)
datafile = open(filename, "r")
thedata = datafile.read()

#create a gridFS object 
filesystem = gridfs.GridFS(db, collection='data')

#write data to GridFS
myfile = filesystem.put(thedata, filename = "countries")
print ("Store to database :)")

#retrieve what was just stored/document
filesystem.get(myfile).read()
```

Comment: We need to see more of your code for this to make sense. If the error is thrown on the line you posted, please provide at least the code for setting the value of `filename`.

Comment: My guess is that it happens because of something in the rest of the code that you didn't show. Specifically, since `filename` is the thing that is `expected` to be `str, bytes or os.PathLike object, not GeojsonFile`, I would guess that the problem is in the place where the value of `filename` is determined.

Comment: i already put my code for u to see.

Comment: It seems like filename is not a path to the file but rather a parsed json object. Can you explain what you expect filename to be or what you're trying to do with this code so that we can understand the problem better?

Comment: I expect filename be the path to the file so that, the file can be retrieve, so the data can be store into the database. Act i want to store big data into the mongoDB using GridFS. i ready connect the database using python. Now i want to read in the spatial data.

Comment: When you do `for feature in filename:`, `feature` holds values that you can store into the database. `filename` is a bad name for the variable because it is not a filename; the `gridfs` library is already handling the file reading for you. It will not work for you to try to open the file yourself at this point.

Answer (score 2):

In your code, `filename` refers to a GeojsonFile object instead of a filename.

If the file you want to read raw is the same file as the file pygeoj reads, then you should do:

```
filename = "/dami_data/test_data/roads.geojson"
geojfile = pygeoj.load(filename)
for feature in geojfile:
    print(feature.geometry.type)
    print(feature.geometry.coordinates)
datafile = open(filename, "r")
thedata = datafile.read()
datafile.close()
```

Though you can do it, you should consider using `geojfile` instead of reading the file again. It already holds information that you needed from that file anyways (as pointed out by [@Karl Knechtel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/523612/karl-knechtel) in the comments).

If not, meaning you want to read a different file, you should pass the filename:

```
filename = "/dami_data/test_data/roads.geojson"
geojfile = pygeoj.load(filename)
for feature in geojfile:
    print(feature.geometry.type)
    print(feature.geometry.coordinates)
datafile = open("my_other_file_name", "r")
thedata = datafile.read()
datafile.close()
```

Last case, if you would like to get the raw data of that GeojsonFile, do:

```
filename = "/dami_data/test_data/roads.geojson"
geojfile = pygeoj.load(filename)
for feature in geojfile:
    print(feature.geometry.type)
    print(feature.geometry.coordinates)
thedata = str(geojfile)
```

Comment: Thank you so much for ur response but sorry when i change that part, I still got the error when running the code such as (AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'), (AttributeError: GridIn object has no attribute 'encoding') and (TypeError: must specify an encoding for file in order to write str). I hope you can help. Im still undergraduate student.

Comment: i already edit and put my code for ur reference if u can point out whats wrong with the code.